# How do find identical pairs in Collection?

Tags: java, collections, set

If I have Collection of Set. And I must find identical pairs in Collection, 
i.e.:

Collection:

- Set {Object_A, Object_B, Object_C}
- Set {Object_A, Object_B, Object_F}

How do find pair: Object_A-Object_B in Collection> ?
What Java library can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a lib, you could use **[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)**, and simply invoke:

```
Sets.intersection(setOne, setTwo);
```

See [`Sets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html)`.`[`intersection()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29).

For instance:

```
Sets.SetView<String> intersectionView = Sets.intersection(
    ImmutableSet.of("Object_A", "Object_B", "Object_C"),
    ImmutableSet.of("Object_A", "Object_B", "Object_D"));
Set<String> intersectionSet = intersectionView.immutableCopy();
```

`intersectionView` will be a view only `"Object_A"` and `"Object_B"` as elements, backed by both original sets. `intersectionSet` will be an immutable set of the intersection.

Refer to the Guava docs for more details and alternatives based on your needs (mutability, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));

Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<>(setA);
intersection.retainAll(setB);
System.out.println("intersection: " + intersection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example will be helpful.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Identical {
      public static void main( String  [] args ) {

          Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("Object_A","Object_B",
                                                    "Object_C");

          Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("Object_A","Object_B",
                                                    "Object_F");

          Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( listOne );
          Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
          different.addAll( listOne );
          different.addAll( listTwo );

          similar.retainAll( listTwo );
          different.removeAll( similar );

      }
}
```